# Sorting date in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting, date

I wanted to sort date in angular js

i'm using

```
  orderBy:predicate :reverse
```

For Example

```
    <div class="list" ng-repeat="user in Stores| orderBy:predicate:reverse">
```

My js has following

```
   $scope.predicate = 'date';
            $scope.reverse = true;
            $scope.order = function (predicate) {
                $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
                $scope.predicate = predicate;
            }

My HTML for sorting date is 

         <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-3 heading-date headerStyle">
          <b class="date-heading" ng-click="order('CreatedDate')">Date</b>
          <span class="sortorder"                                                                                                        
           ng-show="predicate === 'CreatedDate'"                                                                                                                 
           ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
```

I want to sort date in reverse order.How do I sort date in Angular js ?

Comment: What is the problem? How does your data look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
app.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter) {
  var orderBy = $filter('orderBy');
  $scope.Stores = [
   { name: 'John',    phone: '555-1212',    age: '2011-06-11T00:00:00.000Z' },
{ name: 'Mary',    phone: '555-9876',    age: '2011-06-12T00:00:00.000Z' },
{ name: 'Mike',    phone: '555-4321',    age: '2011-07-13T00:00:00.000Z' },
{ name: 'Adam',    phone: '555-5678',    age: '2011-05-14T00:00:00.000Z' },
{ name: 'Julie',   phone: '555-8765',    age: '2011-06-15T00:00:00.000Z' }
  ];
  $scope.order = function(predicate) {
    $scope.predicate = predicate;
    $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
    $scope.friends = orderBy($scope.friends, predicate, $scope.reverse);
  };
  $scope.order('age', true);
}]);
```

HTML PART:

```
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
<body ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <pre>Sorting predicate = {{predicate}}; reverse = {{reverse}}</pre>
    <table class="friend">
      <tr>
        <th>
          <button ng-click="order('name')">Name</button>
          <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === 'name'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
        </th>
        <th>
          <button ng-click="order('phone')">Phone Number</button>
          <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === 'phone'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
        </th>
        <th>
          <button ng-click="order('age')">Age</button>
          <span class="sortorder" ng-show="predicate === 'age'" ng-class="{reverse:reverse}"></span>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="user in Stores|orderBy:predicate:reverse">
        <td>{{user.name}}</td>
        <td>{{user.phone}}</td>
        <td>{{user.age | date:'d MMM yyyy'}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the link for the plunker: [sorting date in reverse order](https://plnkr.co/edit/7XUrMkaEFjloxlsZsGAu?p=preview)

you can keep the dates as ISO 8601
strings which sort naturally and use Angular's date filter to display
the dates.

Found a good example by vojtajina. Here is the jsfiddle for that.
http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/rvdww/6/

Comment: i want know about sorting date

Comment: Works Perfect Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to sort date in angularjs, you can use `orderBy` on date property with `negation`.

For your case, you must be having some date property in your user object. let's say it is `birthdate`, then you can sort in reverse order like this:

```
 <div class="list" ng-repeat="user in Stores| orderBy:'-birthdate'">
```

Answer (score -1):

It might help you http://jsfiddle.net/m7ynD/

*HTML Code*

```
<div ng-app>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.1/angular-1.0.1.js"></script>
    <div ng-controller="Main">
      <div ng-repeat="(id, i) in items | orderBy:'date'">{{id}}: {{i.date | date}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*JavaScript code*

```
function Main($scope) {
    $scope.items = {
        0: {date: new Date('12/23/2013')},
        1: {date: new Date('12/23/2011')},
        2: {date: new Date('12/23/2010')},
        3: {date: new Date('12/23/2015')}
    };
}
```

Comment: This example is not sorting date according to year and month