# How to sort date in table Angular

Tags: angularjs, sorting, date

I take a date from json by using `ng-repeat` in a table. This date looks like this:

> 20_12_2016

I can't sort it by `OrderBy`, because it will only sort the first two numbers (20_12_2016 only "20", ordering stops in "_").

Table looks like this:

```
01_03_2016,
02_01_2016,
02_06_2016...
```

How can I sort by months?

Comment: So to me it looks like you have a list of strings (containing formated dates). In this case you might need to create a custom filter doing the ordering for you. It might take the string-data and convert it into a number which can be compared using the default comparison operators. -  you can read on creating a filter here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: An intersting solution would be to recognize in the app `20_12_2016` as a date, so it will be possible to format it. Don't know how for atm.

Comment: Do some research on how to parse dates in JavaScript (or work with the system that's providing the data to give dates in a standard format, like ISO 8601): http://stackoverflow.com/q/2587345/215552 and how to sort by them in angular: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35402478/215552

Comment: Can you control the format used for the date? If you can have the server supply it YYYY_MM_DD then sorting will 'just work'. Otherwise you will have to provide your own custom comparator.

Comment: You don't find a date format anywhere like this. Not a good practice

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2Vn9CYBrbHVg9UV4V9Qw?p=preview)

```
| orderBy: '+date.substring(3,5)'">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
  app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope,$compile) {

   $scope.sortByDate = function(date) {
      var b = date.split('_').map(Number);
      return b
    }
})




 <div ng-repeat="dateobj in ['20_11_2016','25_11_2016','10_11_2016']  | orderBy:getlastname" >{{dateobj}}</div>
```